# Android SQLite transaction mode vs. JDBC isolation level

Tags: java, android, sqlite, jdbc, transactions

Android `SQLiteDatabase` provides `beginTransaction()` and `beginTransactionNonExclusive()` which pass `TRANSACTION_MODE_EXCLUSIVE` and `TRANSACTION_MODE_IMMEDIATE` respectively, and this leads to `BEGIN IMMEDIATE` or `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE` SQL statements executed.

JDBC `Connection`, on the other hand, does not speak of transaction modes, and provides `TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED`, `TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED`, `TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ`, and `TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE` isolation levels. `org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc` driver supports only SERIALIZABLE and READ_UNCOMMITTED leading to `PRAGMA read_uncommitted = false;` or `PRAGMA read_uncommitted = true;` respectively. But this looks like a different thing, expecially knowing that there's `SQLiteConfig.setTransactionMode(TransactionMode)` (`enum TransactionMode { DEFERRED, IMMEDIATE, EXCLUSIVE }`).

What is the correct idiom for read-only and write transactions which work consistently across Android and JDBC/JVM?